# How to fetch values in sql according to form input?

Tags: mysql

I have a form where users are allowed to enter values and according to that they get results from the database.I have 5 textboxes, my query is such

```
$result=mysql_query("select * from sg_report where DeclarationNo='$dec' JobNo = '$job' ConsigneeName='$cnee' ClaimNo='$claim' OR Status='$t2' OR  ");
```

This gives me proper result if i enter any one value.

If i give `jobNo` as '214' and status as 'completed' it displays records with all rows having `jobNo` as '214' even if status is 'approved' and status as 'completed' even if `jobNo` is '312' but i want to fetch only those records that have `jobNo` 214 and status completed.

How can I achieve that ?

Comment: i think your query gives an error result

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the AND condition in between your statements like :

$result=mysql_query("select * from sg_report where DeclarationNo='$dec' AND JobNo = '$job' ConsigneeName='$cnee' AND ClaimNo='$claim' OR Status='$t2'");

http://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/and.php

Comment: what about between '$job' and ConsigneeName ?

Comment: Oh yes it should be there as well, I missed that, my apologies.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the logic of your SQL query, if you want to retrieve all those rows with a certain JobNo **AND** with a certain status then you need something like:
`select * from sg_report where JobNo = '$job' AND Status='$t2'`

Answer (score 0):

You may need this:

```
$result=mysql_query("select * from sg_report where (DeclarationNo='$dec' OR '$dec'='') AND (JobNo = '$job' OR  '$job'='') AND (ConsigneeName='$cnee' OR '$cnee'='') AND (ClaimNo='$claim' OR '$claim'='') AND (Status='$t2' OR '$t2'='')");
```

Comment: I think it should be like: DeclarationNo='$dec' OR DeclarationNo=''

Comment: @Edrich... No. OP said `This gives me proper result if i enter any one value`, so the OP wants a single query statement implements combinations of 5 different conditions. `DeclarationNo='$dec' OR '$dec'=''` will omit this condition when user doesn't enter `$dec`. If you use `DeclarationNo='$dec' OR DeclarationNo='' ` means `DeclarationNo in ('$dec','')`.

Comment: Ok, lets translate the query into possible result. Let say $dec = 123;
This means DeclarationNo='123' OR '123'='123' ? I think it gives an error result.

Comment: You misunderstanded my query, my query will get `DeclarationNo='123' OR '123'='' ` not `DeclarationNo='123' OR '123'='123' `

Comment: Oh sorry, missed that one. But I think your code gives an error because 123 is not a field on the table.

Answer (score 0):

```
Next time, please include php in your tags because your question contains php code. Also study mysqli or PDO because mysql commands are depreciated.
Your query missed some operators. Try this one.

$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sg_report WHERE DeclarationNo='$dec' AND JobNo = '$job' AND ConsigneeName='$cnee' AND ClaimNo='$claim' AND Status='$t2'");
```